# RazorPages modify routing template

Tags: c#, .net-core, routes, razor-pages

I'm using Razor pages on .net 5.0. I'm trying to find a way to modify the routing template URL to place an ID higher up the path.

The site I'm building runs with multiple projects, and I want to have the projectID high up in the URL, with page-specific IDs still at the end.

As default, I can see I can have /{area (if exists)}/{folder}/{page}/{ID} as a routing structure, and that I could reasonably add more ID's for specific pages (i.e. .../{page}/{projectID}/{pageID}) by setting that in the @page {projectID:string}/{pageID:int?} decration on each page.

**What I'm hoping to achieve is:**

**/{projectID}/{area?}/{folder}/{page}/{ID}**

I can see if I was using the MVC convention I could set a pattern template for endpoints.MapControllerRoute, but is there anything I can do to achieve the above with Razor pages?

Comment: Look at creating a custom `IPageRouteModelConvention`: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/custom-route-conventions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Startup.cs file, find the following line in your ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddRazorPages();
```

Replace it with the following code:

```
services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    // for the pages of the Identity area
    options.Conventions.AddAreaFolderRouteModelConvention("Identity", "/", model =>
        {
        foreach (var selector in model.Selectors)
        {
            var attributeRouteModel = selector.AttributeRouteModel;
            attributeRouteModel.Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates("{projectID=1}", attributeRouteModel.Template);
        }
    });
    // for the default pages
    options.Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention("/", model =>
    {
        foreach (var selector in model.Selectors)
        {
            var attributeRouteModel = selector.AttributeRouteModel;
            attributeRouteModel.Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates("{projectID=1}", attributeRouteModel.Template);
        }
    });
});
```

This will have as a result to add a route value in front of all the urls. All the links will get the value 1 for the project id except if you define one.